# How to access OAuth2 client_id in django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, oauth2-toolkit

I have my django rest framework API protected by Oauth2 toolkit, but I don't know how to get the `client_id` of the current authorized requests.

```
class RequestTransactionView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        transaction = self.parse_dictionary(request.DATA)
        return Response(str(transaction.goid))
```

I have inspected the `request` object, which gave:

```
['DATA', 'FILES', 'QUERY_PARAMS', '_CONTENTTYPE_PARAM', '_CONTENT_PARAM', '_METHOD_PARAM', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_auth', '_authenticate', '_authenticator', '_content_type', '_data', '_default_negotiator', '_files', '_load_data_and_files', '_load_method_and_content_type', '_load_stream', '_method', '_not_authenticated', '_parse', '_perform_form_overloading', '_request', '_stream', '_user', 'accepted_media_type', 'accepted_renderer', 'auth', 'authenticators', 'content_type', 'method', 'negotiator', 'parser_context', 'parsers', 'stream', 'successful_authenticator', 'user']
```

then I inspected the `successful_authenticator` I got:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'authenticate', 'authenticate_header', 'www_authenticate_realm']
```

I also inspected other obvious hints but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier than I thought, when I was printing out `request.auth` I got a string, and I thought it's a string type, but then I figured out it's a AccessToken, so from there I can get the application directly.

```
print request.auth.application
```